# Trying to use Python TestRail API on Mac - ImportError : No module named Conf_Reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror, testrail

I am getting the following import error on Mac:

```
ImportError: No module named Conf_Reader
```

Here are the few initial lines of my Python code:

```
import dotenv
import os
import testrail
import Conf_Reader

#setup the testrail client and connect to the testrail instance
def get_testrail_client():
    testrail_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'testrail.env')
    testrail_url = Conf_Reader.get_value(testrail_file,'TESTRAIL_URL')
    client = testrail.APIClient(testrail_url)
..
..
..
```

So far tried with pip and not able to find any sources for doing its installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem on Mac.
To avoid using other independence you can skip using env. but pass as variable:

```
# create a credential.py
TESTRAIL_URL='https://testrail.com/testrail'
TESTRAIL_USER='xxxxx'
TESTRAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
# on your update_testrail.py
from credential import TESTRAIL_URL, 
TESTRAIL_USER, 
TESTRAIL_PASSWORD

testrail_url = TESTRAIL_URL
client = testrail.APIClient(testrail_url)
# Get and set the TestRail User and Password
client.user = TESTRAIL_USER
client.password = TESTRAIL_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

They should have linked to https://bangladroid.wordpress.com/2016/08/20/create-separate-credential-files-for-selenium-python/

where it explains you make your own ‘Conf_Reader.py’ file is as below:

```
"""
A simple conf reader.
For now, we just use dotenv and return a key.
"""

import dotenv,os

def get_value(conf,key):
    # type: (object, object) -> object
    "Return the value in conf for a given key"
    value = None
    try:
        dotenv.load_dotenv(conf)
        value = os.environ[key]
    except Exception,e:
        print 'Exception in get_value'
        print 'file: ',conf
        print 'key: ',key

    return value
```